# Vitest LitElement events

Tags: testing, storybook, vite, lit-element, vitest

I have a storybook project where i am using Vite and LitElement components.
To test the components i thought i would use the Vitest library.
But i can't really test my components, it is like if the components aren't initialized / mounted / working (but they work fine in the stories., so i think the problem is with the testing).

I have a breadcrumb component, which dispatches a custom event on the `connectedCallback` function. On my story i can listen to this event, so i know it is being dispatched.
But i can seem to test it.

What i have:

1. on the breadcrumb component, inside the `connectedCallback` function

```js
this.dispatchEvent(new Event('abc-breadcrumb-connected'));
```

2. on my breadcrumb.test.ts file:

```js
import type { IWindow } from 'happy-dom';
import { expect, describe, it, beforeEach, vi } from 'vitest';

import '../abc-breadcrumb';
import { AbcBreadcrumb } from "../abc-breadcrumb";


declare global {
    interface Window extends IWindow {}
}

describe('Abc breadcrumb', async () => {
    it('Dispatches connected event', async () => {
        const mockConnectedCallback = vi.fn(() => true);
        window.addEventListener('abc-breadcrumb-connected', () => {
            console.log('GOT THE EVENT');
            mockConnectedCallback()
        });

        document.body.innerHTML = `
            <abc-breadcrumb role="nav" aria-label="Breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb" ismobile="">
                ...
            </abc-breadcrumb>
        `;
        await window.happyDOM.whenAsyncComplete();
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));

        expect(mockConnectedCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
});
```

3. 0n my vite.config.ts i have:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'happy-dom',
    },
    ...
})
```

4. the error i get:

```
AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called at least once
```

I have no idea why it isn't working an would be really happy to get some help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At first look, using `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));` seems like the kind of thing I was unsuccessfully relying on myself to ensure enough ticks had passed for various operations to complete.  This often worked in my local browser but failed in CI or resulted in flaky tests.

Why not set up the promise such that the event listener calls `resolve()` or possibly even `mockConnectedCallback()`.  Then you can be certain the event isn't firing as opposed to only not having been fired when setTimeout resolves.

```js
       const mockConnectedCallback = vi.fn(() => true);
       let connectedResolve;
       const connectedPromise = new Promise(r => connectedResolve = r);
        window.addEventListener('abc-breadcrumb-connected', () => {
            console.log('GOT THE EVENT');
            connectedResolve();
            mockConnectedCallback();
        });

        document.body.innerHTML = `
            <abc-breadcrumb role="nav" aria-label="Breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb" ismobile="">
                ...
            </abc-breadcrumb>
        `;
        await window.happyDOM.whenAsyncComplete();
        await connectedPromise;

        expect(mockConnectedCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

It makes the `expect()` a little redundant given that it won't be reached until the awaited promise resolves, but I think awaiting an explicit resolution makes things easier to reason about and doesn't hard-code various assumptions about microtask queues and things into the test code, which more often than not have come back to bite me later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. that sounds like something that would have been worth trying. I have ended up changing to use the we-test-runner like it is advised by the open-wc. Now it works ok. Thank you anyway...